# manipulating with arrays by address

Tags: ruby, class

Help me with this part of code:

```
class Ooo
 attr_accessor :class_array
end

def func(ctx)
 local_array = ctx.class_array
 local_array = [4,3,5,5,6]
 return
end

aaa = Ooo.new
func(aaa)
aaa.class_array => not [4,3,5,5,6] :-(
```

I supposed that ruby use addresses when operates with arrays...
Why does this code not work?
I want to do this (in C):

```
struct ctx
{
uint class_array[10000]
}

void func(struct *ctx)
{
 uint* local_array = &ctx->class_array
 local_array[0] = 4;
 ctx->class_array[0] => 4
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this part of code:

```
local_array = ctx.class_array
local_array = [4,3,5,5,6]
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. The second line creates a new list and assigns it to the local variable, thus replacing the reference to `ctx.class_array`. It will *not* touch `ctx.class_array`. An equivalent piece of C code would work the same way, so I think you don't only have a Ruby problem here.

In C you could use pointers to solve this. In Ruby you probably want either:

```
local_array = ctx.class_array
local_array.replace [4,3,5,5,6]
```

or simply (much better!)

```
ctx.class_array = [4,3,5,5,6]
```

By the way, the direct translation of your C program would also work:

```
def func(ctx)
  local_array = ctx.class_array
  local_array[4] = 4
end
```

Comment: Big thanks! I just understood! I will use 'replace' than! But what code should i write if i want to append another array to local_array? I mean not just local_array = [something]; if i write local_array += another_array, then ruby also creates new local variable instead of using ctx. variable?

Comment: @user1119425 Because you told it to create a local variable, then assigned the local variable to something else.

Comment: @user1119425: `local_array += another_array` is the same as `local_array = local_array + another array`, so my explanation also applies there. You could use `local_array.push(*another_array)` but it is a good thing that this is ugly. Also, you are invited to upvote and accept if this answer was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the `ctx` instance holds a reference to the array object in the `@class_array` instance variable. In the `func` method, a new reference to that same object is created and assigned to the `local_array` local variable.

When you assign `[4,3,5,5,6]` to `local_array`, you are not overwriting the object referenced by `ctx`, you are overwriting the reference held in `local_array`, making it reference a new array.

In terms of pointers, what you are doing is analogous to this:

```
int array[]     = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int new_array[] = { 4, 3, 5, 5, 6 };

int * ctx_array   = array;
int * local_array = ctx_array;

local_array = new_array; // ctx_array still points to array[0]
```

What I think you want to achieve is this:

```
int ** local_array = &ctx_array;
*local_array = new_array; // ctx_array now points to the new array
```

This kind of indirection is impossible in Ruby. You can only modify an object by calling methods on it.

However, translating your C snippet to Ruby yields fully functional code:

```
def func(ctx)
  local_array = ctx.class_array
  local_array[0] = 4
end

ctx.class_array[0]
 => 4
```

It works because `local_array` refers to the same object as `ctx.class_array`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you skip the first line of your function and just directly assign like so:

```
def func(ctx)
   ctx.class_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
end
```

Comment: Yeah, i know it :-) But I asked "why does this code not work?" )

Comment: It doesn't work because arrays are assigned as copies not pointers in Ruby.

Comment: @Jesse: That's plain wrong. They *are* assigned by reference and *NOT* copied.

Comment: Not when you create a local variable within the method...otherwise his original solution would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Jesse: No it wouldn't. The reference is copied, then the reference is overwritten. No array copying involved. I think you have the exact same problem with understanding this as the OP has.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I mixed up pointers and references--my bad. For some reason I was thinking that it was a pointer, so if he set the value, it would have actually changed the value in memory, but it's really a reference, so when he reassigns it he creates a new array in memory and makes the local variable "refer" to that. Thanks for the clarification, sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by just adjust the order:

```
def func(ctx)
 local_array = [4,3,5,5,6]
 ctx.class_array = local_array
 return
end
```

Comment: why the superflous temporary variable and the return?